# How can I speed up my EF query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I speed up this query?  Right now it's taking me around 2 minutes to pull back 210K records.

I turned off LazyLoading as well as set AsNoTracking on my tables.

I know it's a lot of data but surely it shouldn't take 2 minutes to retrieve the data?

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

List<MY_DATA> data = context
    .MY_DATA.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.MY_DATA_DETAILS)
    .Where(x => startDate <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DB_DATE) 
             && endDate >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DB_DATE)
             && x.MY_DATA_DETAILS.CODE.Trim().ToUpper() == myCode.Trim().ToUpper())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: what about splitting up this query, which apparently brings back a lot of data, into smaller queries? Sometimes smaller queries (even though that means more trips to the db) perform better than 1 giant query.  Also, depending on your db, the need for `ToUpper` could be useless because maybe your database does *case-insensitive* assemblies.

Comment: Have you profiled your database and retrieved a query plan? Are there any missing indexes? This statement here `x.MY_DATA_DETAILS.CODE.Trim().ToUpper() == myCode.Trim().ToUpper()` is written so that it will negate any indexes on your table. It also depends on the size of each record, does the model have large text or byte arrays or something else? Really you are not giving us much to go on, you have to do your research first and then come back and share those results.

Comment: Good point Igor.  However I know in this case that there are no indexes on this field.

Comment: Ok, so you have a table scan across a possibly enormous amount of data that is being returned... most likely not good for performance. You need to include your dbms in the question tag, get the generated query, get the execution plan for the query, and update the question accordingly with that information. Those things usually pin point why a query is slow.

Comment: I'm curious what you plan to do with 210k records at once.

Comment: And again, it could just be the data itself. You did not share your model or the associated `MY_DATA_DETAILS` model you are retrieving. 210K of records and then many details relations could very well just take that long to materialize.

Comment: Can you create, in the database, a computed column with an index for `x.MY_DATA_DETAILS.CODE.Trim().ToUpper()`?

Comment: And how many rows in that table at all?

Comment: 5.7 million records in the main table and the data is used to export out for reporting.

Comment: With that amount of data you application might throw ***out of memory exception*** at one point. If this is just for reporting, you could write a ***SSRS***. SSRS can handle much more efficiently than any application. I'm just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually defining indexes on the columns that you frequently use in the 'where' clause, can improve your performance in selecting the rows from a large tale.

I recommend that you create a stored procedure and move your query into the SP and apply the performance tuning in Database and in your C# code, call the SP.

Comment: `x.MY_DATA_DETAILS.CODE.Trim().ToUpper() == myCode.Trim().ToUpper()` is non-sargable, so an index will make no difference.

Comment: Yes I would agree that indexes would work.  I'm rather limited on the db side on what I can add.  I a trying to work on moving this out to a stored proc, however it's an oracle db so this doesn't prove to be as easy as sql server.

Comment: @JDS As said, indexes won't make any difference if you don't make the query sargable.

Comment: Yes duly noted.  I moved it to a package as was able to reduce the call from 2 minutes to around 40-50 seconds.  I think that's going to be as good as it gets aside from adding an index to the search fields. (Which in testing didn't lead to anything significant)

Answer (score 3):

You can do without `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()` and probably also without these `Trim().ToUpper()` calls.

If you execute a function on a database column before it is filtered, it's impossible for the query optimizer to use any indexes on this column. This is know as being *non-sargable*. To execute the query in its present form, the database engine has to transform the data first and then scan all the transformed data to do the filtering. No index involved.

`DbFunctions.TruncateTime()` is meaningless. You have to choose `startDate` and `endDate` wisely and use `x.DB_DATE` as it is.

Further, if `x.MY_DATA_DETAILS.CODE` is a `varchar` column (most text columns are), it will be auto-trimmed in searches. Even if the database value contains trailing spaces, they will be ignored. So `Trim` isn't necessary. Next, most text columns by default have a case-insensitive database collation. You should check it. If this is SQL Server, look for collations like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. The `CI` part means Case-Insensitive. If so, you can also do away with the `ToUpper` part. If *not*, you can either change the collation to a case-insensitive one, or you maybe should conclude that the column is case sensitive for a reason, so it does matter whether you look for `Abc` or `abc`.

Either way, having these transforming function removed form the database columns, the query should be able to run considerably faster, provided that proper indexes are in place.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need all the attributes of the object? 
You can do this.

```
    List<MY_DATA> data = context.MY_DATA.Include(x =>
        x.MY_DATA_DETAILS).Where(x => startDate <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DB_DATE) &&
        endDate >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DB_DATE) &&
        x.MY_DATA_DETAILS.CODE.Trim().ToUpper() == myCode.Trim().ToUpper()).select(x => new MY_DATA()
        {
            Value = data
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other guy said about moving your query to a stored proc and creating the proper indexes, I'd say you'd be better off using SQL reporting rather then trying to import the data into your application and reporting from there. Especially 210K rows. SQL has internal optimizations that you'll never be able to come close to with stored procs and queries.

You can see this very easily:

1) try write a simple console app that tries to pull down that entire table and writes it to a CSV file -- it'll be *extremely* slow.

2) try use the data export through Sql Mgmt Studio and export to a CSV -- it'll be done in a few seconds.